# Understanding Throughput of interfaces problem on Cisco Routers

Tags: cisco-ios, network, snmp, iperf, traffic

I have the following topology set on *AWS* where there are 4 *CSR 1000v Routers* deployed and **Segment Routing** enabled in which the **Segment Routing Headend** is *R1* and the destination is *R3*.

I aim to send **iperf** traffic from ***Endpoint1(Client)*** to ***Endpoint2 (Server)*** with the following *SR path* = {*R1, R2, R3, R4, R3, R2, R1, R2, and R3*}. 
[image]
First of all, the traffic generated by **iperf** from ***Endpoint1*** is `5Mbps` during the test. Using **SNMP** and **Cacti** I could get throughput across the links *(GRE Tunnels)* which are summarized in the following:

[image]
The router *R1* is being passed 2 times because of *SR policy*, so it should have had 2 times of the traffic sent (`5Mbps`) which means `10Mbps` as *Outbound throughput*. However, The *R1* the interface `Gigabitethernet1` got nearly `7Mbps` as *Outbound throughput* and fewer than `7Mbps` on the Inbound, (because the *R1* has been passed twice `7Mbps/2= 3.5Mbps` for one time passed) which I really don't understand why. I double checked there are no packet drops on the router.

Another argument that the traffic sent to the other nodes in one time is `3.5Mbps` is recorded in `Tunnel0` of *R1* as the below figure shows, the *Inbound Throughput* is nearly `3.5Mbps`, which means the real traffic sent across the network nodes is `3.5Mbps` not as **iperf** generate 5Mbps.
[image]

Here I provide some figures to better understand. The following is the `GiabitEthernet1` of *R4*.
[image]

Another interesting point is why the `Gigabitethernet1` of *R2* and *R3* recorded `10Mbps`?
[image]
[image]
Does anybody have assumptions or theories?

Comment: erm... not that it would relate to performance, but the network diagram shows /32 subnet masks for the tunnel interfaces, but seems to say that .1 and .2 were interface IP addresses at the end of the given tunnels. That can't be right. Either the subnet mask on the tunnel is different ( where /30 would make .1 and .2 plausible), or it's something else - but _not_ /32.  Also be aware 172.[0--15].x.x are NOT RFC 1918 private IP addresses. Avoid using them.  172.[16-31].x.x would be safe to use.

Comment: CSRs usually come with a global traffic shaper which limits the total throughput. You wouldn't happen to run the 10Mbps license, would you?

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Thanks! I have edited the tunnels' mask. It is for  /30 just typo mistake while I was doing the figure. I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by **10Mbps Licence**. Also, if using `172.[0--15].x.x` would face problem? I thought it's a private network.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Well, I have read about *10Mbps license* thing. (https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/cloud-services-router-1000v-series/data_sheet-c78-733443.html) Obviously, My CSRs are deployed in _t2.medium_ EC2 instance type, with 2vCPU and 4Gb RAM, so I think It may support more than 10Mbps

Comment: be sure to check with `show platform hardware throughput level` and/or `show license` (and subcommands).

Comment: A private network it may be.  It is still "illegal" IP adressing which will earn you more or less harsh criticism from any responsibly acting network admin.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi it is The current throughput level is `200000000 kb/s`

Comment: 200Gbit/s ? I say! This must be related to the AWS flavour of the given CSR1000V, althoug _Table 9_ in the document you linked makes no reference to such an immense throughput level.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Cisco CSR does not have support for SR on AWS, see [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/configuration/b_CSR1000v_Configuration_Guide.pdf#page=29) for AWS requirements/support.</s> *There is no support for SR as in SR-IOV "single root virtualization", there is support for SR as in segment routing.*

ALso keep in mind that AWS EC2 performance varies by instance type. The AWS Marketplace page for the CSR 1000v [lists](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01IAFXXVO#pdp-pricing) lists 4 instance types. Though not published by AWS, there have been EC2 performance tests with [published results](https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/) that show the following baseline numbers for performance:

- c4.large (0.62 Gbit/s)
- c4.xlarge (1.24 Gbit/s)
- c4.2xlarge (2.48 Gbit/s)
- c4.4xlarge (4.96 Gbit/s)

Comment: Thanks, @Nathan L.! Well, the SR on AWS is working. My CSRs are having SR enabled and 100% working according to the given explicit path. On the other hand, I'm using EC2 _t2.meduim_ that has _0.25 Gbps_ network performance, means throughput cannot exceed _250 Mbps_  but in my case, I'm somehow losing some packets before it arrives at the router.

Comment: Just edited my response, I misread your post. I meant a different kind of SR. I'm wondering if the poor performance you're seeing is a result of how AWS abstracts the TCP/IP stack-- there's no TCP/IP under the hood, just a series of catalog calls. Perhaps the traffic isn't behaving as expected in a regular TCP/IP network because of this?

Comment: To be honest, I cannot understand this behavior. I really don't know from where it comes from :/

Comment: What does the underlying AWS topology? Is each router a different VPC, subnet, etc.?

Comment: Yes! Each router is deployed in different VPC in subnets. VPC peering is enabled between the VPCs (_VPC1-VPC2, VPC2-VPC3, VPC3-VPC4_ and _VPC1-VPC4_ peering connections)

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Is this for a lab or a real world work load? This isn't a common design in cloud. Curious what you're going for.

Comment: yes, it is! I used SR for the Service Function Chaining where an SR enabled node can be passed multiple times upon the Network Functions and SFC.